# How to make wildcard search with fuzzy search in Lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have created lucene.net index projects. in this project if I put ~ symbol it act as a fuzzy search.

My code is,

```
var hits = indexSearcher.Search(QueryMaker(searchString+"~" , searchfields));
```

Now, I want to make wildcard search with the existing fuzzy search. Is it possible to make both search?

Comment: You could use the logic mentioned here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897641/fuzzy-wildcard-search-together-in-lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897641/fuzzy-wildcard-search-together-in-lucene)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is actually pretty well documented, so is the query language:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Never tried but maybe it is possible to have wildcards within the search string (before the ~)?

Apart from that, here is another post with a similar issue
[Combining Lucene's WildcardQuery with FuzzyQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296205/combining-lucenes-wildcardquery-with-fuzzyquery)

Comment: hi all,
i got the answer..
 Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
            finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
            finalQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);