# fuzzy + wildcard search together in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have list of device make & models ...
E.g.
"Samsung Galaxy S23",
"Samsung Galaxy S22",
"Apple iphone 14",
"Apple iphone pro max"
etc etc

Each item in the list has multiple words.
Using `Lucene`, I want to search for the word entered by the user. I want the search to be wild card based as well as fuzzy so that even if the user makes minor spelling mistakes, the correct search is done.
for e.g.

| Input | expected result | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| samsung | Samsung Galaxy S23, Samsung Galaxy S22 | wild card query works well in this case |
| iphone | Apple iphone 14, Apple iphone pro max | wild card query works well in this case |
| smasung | Samsung Galaxy S23, Samsung Galaxy S22 | HOW DO I MAKE THIS WORK ??? |

the 3rd input above (misspelt input) is is the problematic one that I need help with. If my index only has single word entries, Fuzzy search is able to match "smasung" with "samsung". But how do I combine it with wildcard search so that "smasung" will match "Samsung Galaxy S23" as well as "Samsung Galaxy S22"

Wild card query works well, it need correctly spelled search string.
Fuzzy query works well only if the input string is of almost the same length with very minor mistakes as the index entries. It does not return any results, if I search with just a part of the string ... E.g. search for "Smasung" will match "samsung", but not "Samsung Galaxy S23" ...

How do I get it to work to achieve the effect of fuzziness + wildcard ?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to achieve it using spell checker on a custom dictionary. The logic i used is as follows:

When loading each device from my DB into a lucene index for search, added each `<space>` separated substring from the name into custom dictionary.
for e.g. if the device name was "samsung galaxy s24 ultra", i added the words "samsung", "galaxy", "s24" & "ultra" into the dictionary.

This way, I created a dictionary that contains only those terms that are relevant for my context.

Next was the creation of the correct query:
Here I separated each word in the input string and used the following logic to identify the term to be used for searching:

```
1. check if the term exists in the dictionary
1.1. if it exists - use the term as is (this step is important because if the term is found in the dictionary, it will not be returned as part of `spellChecker.suggestSimilar(...)` 
1.2. if it does not exist - find similar terms from the dictionary using `spellChecker.suggestSimilar(...)`
1.2.1. if found, i took the first 5 results from the returned terms 
1.2.2. if not found, use the term as is (this is important in case the input is of a partial word - e.g. "amsu" where spellchecker may not return any results, the results should include all that contain "amsu" - e.g. "samsung....")
```

I then used a `BooleanQuery.Builder` and added wildcard queries for each term in the input (after running them thru the dictionary as mentioned above) using `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST` (for cases where the suggested terms were retrieved from spellchecker, i added all of them to an inner query - using `BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD`)

This query works well for me. For the input "*smasung galay*", spellcheck corrects the terms to "*Samsung*" & "*Galaxy*" respectively and then it searches for all devices that include "*Samsung*" & "*Galaxy*" within their names.

Hope this helps :)